# Dependency injection with many subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class in Guice that gets ~10 argument in the constructor using dependency injection.

This class has many derived classes. 
The constructors of all the derived classes are just passing all the argument to super.

Adding a new argument to the constructor of the base class would require to add this argument to all the constructors of all the derived class.

```
    class MyBaseClass {
        @Inject
        MyBaseClass(arg1,arg2,arg3, ..., argn) {
            this.arg1 = arg1
            ....
        }

    }

    class MyDerivedClass1 extends MyBaseClass{
        @Inject
        MyDerivedClass1(arg1,arg2,arg3, ..., argn) {
            super(arg1,arg2,arg3, ..., argn)
        }    
    }

    class MyDerivedClass2 extends MyBaseClass{
        @Inject
        MyDerivedClass2(arg1,arg2,arg3, ..., argn) {
            super(arg1,arg2,arg3, ..., argn)
        }    
    }
```

One solution I had is to wrap all the arguments in one class and inject that class to the base class and all the derived classes. This way when adding a new argument to that injected class it will be injected to all the derived classes.

Something like:

```
    class MyBaseClassSettings {
        @Inject
        MyBaseClassSettings(arg1,arg2,arg3, ..., argn) {
         this.arg1 = arg1
         ...
        }
    }

    class MyBaseClass {
        @Inject
        MyBaseClass(MyBaseClassSettings settings) {
            this.settings = settings;
        }

    }

    class MyDerivedClass1 extends MyBaseClass{
        @Inject
        MyDerivedClass1(MyBaseClassSettings settings) {
            super(settings)
        }    
    }

    class MyDerivedClass2 extends MyBaseClass{
        @Inject
        MyDerivedClass2(MyBaseClassSettings settings) {
            super(settings)
        }    
    }
```

Assuming that the args are not really related to each other (one is a connection to the DB, the other is an helper that's assigning threads to tasks, another one does parts of the actual logic, and another one holds geographical configuration for the class... (just examples)) Would this solution considered to be ok?

In case it is, what would be a good naming for the wrapper class?

Comment: While this approach is ok, you should check if all this args paramaters do not have anything in common ... maybe you discover that instead of "the settings" you could derive "the database settings", "the user settings", ... and use multiple meaningful wrappers .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pragmatically speaking, your solution is OK. You can solve your problem this way and that will not cost you a lot of time.

Having said that, if you have time, you should probably refactor the code and split the class into multiple classes.

Having 10 dependencies is a sign that your class is doing much, and is considered a code smell (take a look at [this](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/constructor-over-injection-smell-ndash-follow-up/)). Your class seems to be having too many responsibilities and thus is violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Consider [Aggregated Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) for a potential fix to your problem.

Depending on your situation you can choose to do your suggested fix for now and refactor later when you have time. Take a look at the concept of [Technical Debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

As for the name of the class, your suggested one is fine. Another suggestion would be `MyBaseClassDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perfectly reasonable solution and a common idiom for hierarchies.

Your name would be fine. Another naming pattern would be `BaseParams` or `BaseClassParams`, etc.

Comment: In this case what would be a better approach to access the fields.
Assign them like this:
this.db = params.db  and then access them without a change
or replace all occurances of this.db to this.params.getDb()

Comment: Probably the former, assuming it has getters: this.db = params.getDb(). It will be more conventional and alike to your other code, including subclasses.